# Sampling raster data around point set in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point, buffer, sampling

**I have the following problem**: I have a set of 27 "destinations" which I have selected manually and saved as a POINT layer. I have loaded several raster data layers into my project (with varying pixel sizes), and I would like to sum the raster values (for example pregnancy data) within a given radius around each of these 27 destination points, so that in the end I have the sum of annual pregnancies (for example) in a 3km radius around each of these predefined points.

**What I have tried**: I have used the "Buffer" tool, to create circles with a radius of 3km around each of these points, and have then used the "Rasterize (vector to raster)" tool to convert these circles to a raster layer. I then tried to use the "Raster layer zonal statistics" tool to get the data associated with each destination.

The problem is that since the result is a single raster layer, I cannot get the destination-specific data I was hoping for, just the sum total and mean of all annual pregnancies around all 27 destinations in my case.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: What you need is **Zonal statistics** tool, not `Raster layer zonal statistics`. And you do not have to rasterize; just use your buffer (vector layer) as is.

Comment: Thank you!! I think that worked as intended - I was just manually checking the sum count, but you're right it bypasses the rasterization step

Comment: Glad to know it worked. If you still want to work on **Raster layer zonal statistics**, you would need to rasterize the polygon according to each destination numbers (1, 2, ..., 27). I am afraid, when you rasterized the buffer layer, it might have had only one value such as 1.  That's why I recommended **Zonal statistics** tool instead.

Comment: @Kazuhito, I think your comment(s) deserve to become a valid answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Taras It may take a while for me to prepare an example to explain what (might) have happened, but will do definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer to try to explain **Raster layer zonal statistics**.

(1) An example of a raster layer and an overlying Buffer polygon layer.

[image]

(2) Rasterize the polygon; assign `Destinations` as the input field. (To rasterize, I used `SAGA > Raster - Rasterizing > Polygons to Raster` tool).

[image]

(3) Start **Raster layer zonal statistics** tool.

[image]

(4) It will return `Statistics` table with `area(m2), sum, cell count, min, max, mean` values.

[image]

Using the tool itself is straghtforward, but the `Rasterize` step is tricky. Today I had problem with **GDAL Rasterize (vector to raster)** tool, which output layer is misplaced for whatever reasons...

Anyway, I would suggest **Zonal statistics** tool; as we can go without rasterizing task.